# Filter markers between a certain price range

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, marker

I'm trying to make a function that filters all the markers that are between a certain price range, however I cannot make it work. I tried it using the code below.

What am I doing wrong?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaj1b018/)

```js
function priceRange(){      
    var price1 = document.getElementById('price1').value;
    var price2 = document.getElementById('price2').value;

    for(i = 0; i < markers.length; i++){
        marker = gmarkers[i];

        if(marker.price > price1 && marker.price < price2){
            mark.setVisible(true);
        }
        else{
            mark.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THe input field values are strings, you need to parse them to number for the comparisons to work properly. Use `parseInt(str, 10)` or `parseFloat(str)` depending on the kind of number you use. Remove the thousands separator from the string before parsing it:

```
var price1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('price1').value.replace(/\./g, ''), 10);
var price2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('price2').value.replace(/\./g, ''), 10);
```

Parse the marker prices in the same way (as charlietfl pointed out):

```
if(parseInt(marker.price.replace(/\./g, ''), 10) > price1 && parseInt(marker.price.replace(/\./g, ''), 10) < price2){
```

To make the code in the fiddle work you need to put the Javascript code in the head without a wrapper, inside a `load` event but with the `priceRange` function outside it so that it's reachable from the button event. Change the attribute in the button from `onlick` to `onclick`: http://jsfiddle.net/jaj1b018/3/

Comment: and same for marker object price which is also string